# How to pass custom variables of a tag to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the html like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="13" jobtitile="UI Designer (Web Designer / Team Leader)" onclick="postResume(this.id,this.jobtitle);" class="InsideRightBoxLink">Submit Application</a>
```

java script function is:

```
function postResume(jobId,jobtitle){  
alert(jobtitle);  
//alert($("#"+jobId).attr('jobTitle'));  
}
```

Both are giving the undefined, Please help me thanks.

Comment: For such questions first create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobtitile` is not HTML valid attribute so use `getAttribute` function

change

```
this.jobtitile
```

To

```
this.getAttribute("jobtitile")
```

Try this code

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="13" 
 jobtitile="UI Designer (Web Designer / Team Leader)" 
    onclick="postResume(this.id,this.getAttribute("jobtitile"));"
 class="InsideRightBoxLink">Submit Application</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function postResume(obj){  
alert(obj.id);  
alert(obj.getAttribute("jobtitile"));  
}  
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="13" jobtitile="UI Designer (Web Designer / Team Leader)" 
onclick="postResume(this);" class="InsideRightBoxLink">Submit Application</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

getting attributes values in javascript is different from jQuery.
use this.getAttribue('attributeName');

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="13" jobtitle="UI Designer (Web Designer / Team Leader)" onclick="postResume(this.id,this.getAttribute('jobtitle'));" class="InsideRightBoxLink">Submit Application</a> 


<script>
function postResume(jobId,jobtitle){  
alert(jobtitle);  
//alert($("#"+jobId).attr('jobTitle'));  
} 
</script>
```